# Aix equivalent of tcp_retries2

Tags: networking, aix, tcp

please help me with Aix equivalent of tcp_retries2 parameter that is available Linux machines.
Found this link in SO
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892502/aix-equivalent-of-the-following-linux-parameters

and followed up searching in 
http://unix.stackexchange.com
and 
https://superuser.com/

But didn't got the answer yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the difference between Linux's tcp_retries1 and tcp_retries2.  But the basic answer to your question is the `rto_length` option from the `no` command.

```
no -a | grep rto 
             rto_high = 64
           rto_length = 13
            rto_limit = 7
              rto_low = 1
          tcp_low_rto = 0
```

Those are the guys you want to focus on (except for tcp_low_rto).  But, speaking of tcp_low_rto, AIX has two methods.  The normal and also a "low rto" method that has its own set of no options.

`no -h <option>` provides some information on these parameters.